# Remove cache name from generated cache key

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I would like to know if there is some way to remove the cache name from the generated cache key on Spring boot 2.

This is the code i'm currently using to cache data:

```
@Cacheable(value = "products", key = "#product.id")
public SimilarProducts findSimilarProducts(Product product){}
```

Spring boot is concatenating the string "products" to every single key i'm generating to save on the cache. I have already tried to make my own key generator but the spring boot keeps concatenating the string "products" to the generated keys. Thanks for your attention.

For example when i use:

```
Product p = new Product();
p.setId("12345");
findSimilarProducts(p);
```

The generated key will be:

```
products::12345
```

I would like it to be only 12345.

Comment: can you provide working code and what is your expected output and how it is working right now ?

Comment: I have just edited the question, and this is the default behaviour i only have a product class with an id.

Comment: how did you get your result?

Comment: I saw my result on the Redis server after sprint boot did the insertion.

Answer (score 3):

> spring boot keeps concatenating the string "products" to the generated keys.

Spring Boot (or the cache abstraction for that matter) doesn't do such thing but a particular `Cache` implementation might. It would have been interesting to share a bit more details about your setup but I can only guess you are using Redis as the cache store and the default `CacheKeyPrefix` adds the name of the cache indeed.

Please review [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis:support:cache-abstraction).

Comment: Your answer made me go to: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html where i discovered the option: spring.cache.redis.use-key-prefix=false which disables the cache implementation to write the prefix. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can (maybe you need to) disable key prefix like this.

```
@Bean
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = RedisCacheManager.builder(connectionFactory)
            .cacheDefaults(defaultCacheConfig().disableKeyPrefix())
            .build();
    return cacheManager;
}
```